# How do I catch import errors from read_stata function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I am trying to write a function that imports data from a Stata .dta file using the pandas read_stata function. I would like to detect any problems with the read process (for example, file doesn't exist) using something akin to:

```
try:  
    data = read_stata('filename.dta')  
except someTypeOfException:  
    print "Error"  
    exit(0)
```

so I can print a message and exit gracefully (sorry, can't get the indents to work). However, I can't find any information about the Exceptions raised by read_stata if there is a problem. I'm new to python and pandas and I may not be expressing my web searches correctly. Or I may be barking up the wrong tree altogether, of course. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too broad. There are too many possible exceptions: some of them may be related to `read_stata()`, some may be not. The one you mentioned, file doesn't exist, would result in a `IOerror`, which is not even `read_stata` related.

To see all the possible exceptions that may be raised by `read_stata()`, go check its source code, located in `<path to pandas>/io/stata.py`. This should give you a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Much appreciated. That gives me a good starting point.